# Rails: testing a custom validator for several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, dry

I have a custom validator to test my tax number of different organisation types. I was wondering if it's possible to test it with Rspec, passing different models to the tests, to keep things DRY.

app/models/restaurant.rb

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  validates :tax_number, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_with TaxNumberValidator
end
```

app/models/supplier.rb

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  validates :tax_number, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_with TaxNumberValidator
end
```

This is how my spec file looks now, but ideally instead of testing separately for each model, I would like to pass any instance with an attribute `:tax_number` to test if valid.

```
describe TaxNumberValidator do
  with_model :restaurant do
    table do |t|
      t.string :tax_number
    end

    model do
      validates :tax_number, tax_number: true
    end
  end

  it 'should be valid with a valid tax number' do
    expect(Fabricate(:restaurant)).to be_valid
  end

  it 'should be invalid without an tax number' do
    expect(Fabricate.build :restaurant, tax_number: '').not_to be_valid
  end

  it 'should be invalid with an invalid tax number' do
    expect(Fabricate.build :restaurant, tax_number: '111').not_to be_valid
    expect(Fabricate.build :restaurant, tax_number: 'abc').not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surround the whole `describe` with `%i[restaraunt supplier].each`?

Comment: Perhaps a use case for [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)?

Comment: Your testing strategy looks backwards to be. As @zwippie suggests, it would make more sense to have something like `it_behaves_like 'tax number validations'` in each model spec, rather than looping through each model in the validator spec. Your model specs should all be in one place, not spread across multiple files like that.

Comment: @TomLord Would it be possible though to test the validator in isolation, rather than repeating the same tests in all models that make use of it?

Comment: @zwippie I was reading about the shared examples before but had no idea how to implement it in this case...

Comment: If your tests don't need to touch the database -- and nothing in your post indicates that they do -- then they should run very fast; you're best off to just repeat a set of shared tests for each model.

Comment: *Could* you test the validator in isolation? Yes, but - for the reasons I keep repeating above - that wouldn't be the best idea. You could either just give it one 'arbitrary' model to run tests on, or use a mock object. (But if you use a mock, you should really also be ensuring that all of your models satisfy your mock's interface!)

Comment: Additionally, and slightly off topic, if you will have more of these classes it might make more sense to store the tax numbers in a table of their own and use a polymorphic relationship. This will isolate the validation process while offering the ability to apply this functionality unilaterally to all objects that need a tax number. Also given the assumption that all tax numbers would most likely be unique a single source of truth makes this easier too.